# How do I get a UILabel text to change randomly?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I get a UILabel text to change randomly?

```
@IBOutlet weak var stoptimer: UILabel!
stoptimer.text = String(arc4random_uniform(10))
```

Comment: hey @user3358638, it is very difficult to tell what exactly you are asking and how to help you with our problem. could you provide a bit more context to your issue?

Comment: I got it to work, but how do I range the numbers from 1-10 rather 0-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer your last question as to how to generate random numbers ranging from 1 to 10 (instead of 0 to 10):

```
 int i = arc4random_uniform(9)+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple functions for that:

```
func random(#min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> Int {
    return Int(random() * (max - min) + min)
}

func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
stoptimer.text = String(random(min: 1, max: 10))
```

Here you can change minimum and maximum values as per your need.